# Why is the official Mongo Docker image not reading /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d in an ECS environment?

Tags: mongodb, docker, amazon-ecs

I have created a task in Amazon ECS based on the mongo:latest docker image, I have configured the environment with the following:

```
MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=mydb
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=root_password
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
```

I have also mapped the following volumes:

```
/mongo/data:/data/db                          # This is an EFS access point,
/mongo/scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d    # another EFS access point.
```

I have a script called `secure_mongo.js` in the `/mongo/scripts` access point (I think the `use mydb` line is superfluous based on the mongo image docs q.v.):

```
use mydb

db.createUser({
        user: 'user_name',
        pwd: 'password',
        roles: [ { role: 'readWrite', db: 'mydb' } ]
});
```

According to the mongo:latest docs on Docker Hub:

> When a container is started for the first time it will execute files with extensions .sh and .js that are found in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d. Files will be executed in alphabetical order. .js files will be executed by mongo using the database specified by the MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE variable, if it is present, or test otherwise. You may also switch databases within the .js script.

However it seems that nothing is run, when my application attempts to connect I see the following output:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-18T03:48:41.834+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":20251,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"Supported SASL mechanisms requested for unknown user","attr":{"user":"user_name@mydb"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-18T03:48:41.836+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":20249,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"Authentication failed","attr":{"mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-256","principalName":"user_name","authenticationDatabase":"mydb","client":"10.0.17.73:53488","result":"UserNotFound: Could not find user \"user_name\" for db \"mydb\""}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-18T03:48:41.840+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":20249,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"Authentication failed","attr":{"mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-1","principalName":"user_name","authenticationDatabase":"mydb","client":"10.0.17.73:53488","result":"UserNotFound: Could not find user \"user_name\" for db \"mydb\""}}
```

My application connection url is `mongodb://mongo-srvc.local:27017/mydb` so it should be authenticating against the `mydb` database where the user should be.  To validate the volume was in place I have connected into the running instance and I can see the script I wrote in the directory `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`.  In fact I also added a short shell script `foo.sh` to this directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
touch "./baa.txt"
```

On re-starting the container no `baa.txt` was to be found so it looks like the content of this folder is never executed.  I am also not sure if the environment variables are being used.  I attempted to run the mongo shell using:

```
mongo --username root --password --authenticationDatabase admin
```

This then prompted for the password, when I gave the password it returned:

```
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?authSource=admin&compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: Authentication failed. :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

However I am not an expert on the mongo shell so I could have got that last test incorrect.  Any advise on what I can try next, what I have misconfigured or just got plain wrong is very welcome!

Comment: You should write a script that echoes something and look for that output in the ecs task output.

Comment: And link to docs you are referencing please.

Comment: Add complete task output to the question.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that `/mongo/data` does not contain a db already (e.g. from a first test run before you added the scripts )? The doc statement `When a container starts for the first time...` should be understood as `... for the first time with a totally empty data dir...`. Else initialization will not take place at all.

Comment: Huge thanks to @Zeitounator, spot on I was conflating container init with db init... *doh* Just to help others if you are running this as a services it's easiest to delete the service, remove the db files and recreate the service.  Just stopping the task in ECS led to it still seeing stale files!

Comment: @D.SM, I had tried echo and a console log but was getting nothing, the touch was used in case there was any output redirect going on.  The docs can be found [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo).